# ¿Cómo hacer privado el método construct en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Se puede crear constructores privados en un lenguaje de programación para esta pregunta seria en el lenguaje php?
ejemplo.:

```
//clase ejemplo
class ejemplo{

   // aqui es mi duda puedo definir un constructor privado
   private function __constructor(){}

  // o el estandar de php no lo permite y tiene que ser como esta establecido
  public function __constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: gracias ya lo voy a editar para hacer mas amplia la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varios escenarios en los que es posible que desee que tu constructor sea privado. La razón más común es que, en algunos casos, no deseas que el código externo llame directamente al constructor, sino que lo obligue a usar otro método para obtener una instancia de su clase.

### Singleton pattern

*Solo quieres que exista una sola instancia de la clase:*

```php
class Singleton
{
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

### Factory method

*Deseas proporcionar varios métodos para crear una instancia de su clase, y/o deseas controlar la forma en que se crean sus instancias, porque se necesita algún conocimiento interno del constructor para llamarlo correctamente:*

```php
class Decimal
{
    private $value; // constraint: a non-empty string of digits
    private $scale; // constraint: an integer >= 0

    private function __construct($value, $scale = 0)
    {
        // Value and scale are expected to be validated here.
        // Because the constructor is private, it can only be called from within the class,
        // so we can avoid to perform validation at this step, and just trust the caller.

        $this->value = $value;
        $this->scale = $scale;
    }

    public static function zero()
    {
        return new self('0');
    }

    public static function fromString($string)
    {
        // Perform sanity checks on the string, and compute the value & scale

        // ...

        return new self($value, $scale);
    }
}
```

<sup>Ejemplo simplificado de la implementación [BigDecimal](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/master/src/BigDecimal.php) de  [brick/math](https://github.com/brick/math)</sup>

### Acá te dejo un articulo (en inglés) con más detalles.

Link: https://medium.com/@liamhammett/private-constructors-324a1384f8f2

Answer (score 1):

Si tu defines el método *constructor* (**`__construct()`**) de una clase, cuando requieras hacer la instancia y pasar los argumentos que cada parámetro de tu clase espera, obtendrías un error como este:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to private SomeAlgo::__construct() from invalid context in [...][...]:12

Entonces a este punto, el método *constructor* de la clase debería tener un modificador de acceso como público.

Por otro lado, lo que puedes hacer es construir una implementación de: *static factory method*:

- Declara al método *constructor* como privado
- Crea otro método *público y de tip estático*

  - este método por dentro retornará una instancia de la clase misma en la cual esta contenido
  - esperará recibir como argumento un valor para la propiedad que el constructor de la clase

**Ejemplo basado y funcionando en PHP 7.4 o superior**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

class laClase
{
    private int $valor;
    protected function __construct($valor)
    {
        $this->valor = $valor;
    }

    public static function setValor(int $valor): laClase
    {
        return new laClase($valor);
    }
}

var_dump(laClase::setValor(123));
```

Con una salida como esta:

```
object(laClase)#1 (1) {
  ["valor":"laClase":private]=>
  int(123)
}
```

**Fuentes consultadas**

- [Explicación sobre la implementación de *Static Factory Method*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCJJ7rf087Y)